# Using an IF statement in my SiteMaster.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

In my **SiteMaster.cs** file I want to be able to run an IF statement based on the current page the user is on.

I'm currently getting the file name using: `currentPage.Text = this.Page.ToString().Substring(4, this.Page.ToString().Substring(4).Length - 5) + ".aspx";` but I'd like to then use this to run an IF statement.

It would basically be like `(if currentPage == "default.aspx") { // do this }`

I'm very new to .NET and taking on a existing project.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the page name from the `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`.

```
if(Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("Default.aspx"))
```

Or, below will return `Default.aspx`

```
Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Substring(Request.Url.AbsolutePath.LastIndexOf('/')+1)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, Muhammad. Many thanks once more for your speedy and patience with me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its alot better to compare type.  Every page is a class.

```
if(Page is _Default)
{
    // do work
}
```

If you have to import a namespace and you have visual studio 2010 you can highlight _Default and holding CTRL + .

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I could not get this working. I get the error: `The type or namespace name 'Default' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Default is an example of what your page class name could be.  also if you have your pages in a different folder/namespace than your master page then you may need to add a using statement.  Look at the code behind of the page you want to check for and see what its class type is.  Also not the namespace it is in.

Comment: Apologies. I'm very new to this. In 'Default.aspx.cs' I have: `public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page` so does this mean my page class name is '_Default'? I have the master and 'Default.aspx' in the same folder. Thanks again